# How does EOS deployed their token contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, go-ethereum

I want to create a crowdsale token contract similar to EOS. I am new to crowdsale token contract. I get the source code from etherscan.io. They are EOSTokenContract, EOSCrowdsale, EOS-Owner. I want to know how did they deployed their smart contract. Through truffle? or what kind of framework to deploy their smart contract. 
Can i deploy a similar crowdsale contract using those three files?

Comment: Try asking at [EOS.io site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/116927/eosio/visit).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to take a look to [OpenZeppelin](https://openzeppelin.org/), they provide a good library to develop Smart Contracts, with good tutorials and guides and a specific focus on crowdsale contracts.

You can start from their basic example ["How To Create Token and Initial Coin Offering Contracts Using Truffle + OpenZeppelin"](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6)

Comment: Yeah, i know truffle and OpenZeppelin, but i don't think that EOS used truffle.

Answer (score 0):

In EOS contract is written in C++ language while in ethereum in solidity. SO you can't deploy using truffle because it's not yet developed for EOS.